# Retrieving image links in Prestashop 1.5.6 hookActionProductAdd

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I need to retrieve all image links associated with a particular product in Prestashop 1.5.6 hookActionProductAdd . I dont see them in the $params parameter, how do I have to do to retrieve them in the case they arent there?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the getImages() method;

```
$id_lang = (int)Context::getContext()->language->id;    
$images = $params['product']->getImages($id_lang);
```